Drop Cap is causing text to be pushed out on certain lines of text

I would like the text to stay flush but it looks like the superscript along with the dropcap to be pushed out. I don't know what I need to fix that. Also, I'd like the paragraph to wrap around the drop cap where the first line starts at the top of it. Can some one help me? Thank-you!
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lettrine} % For creating drop caps
\usepackage{yfonts}   % For Goudy Initialen font
\usepackage{xcolor} % Provides \textcolor
% Set the page geometry with default text width
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=9.4in,
    paperheight=6.8in,
    headheight=0pt, % Remove header
    headsep=0pt,    % Remove space for header
    footskip=0pt,   % Remove footer
    marginparwidth=0pt, % Remove marginal notes
    marginparsep=0pt,   % Remove separation for marginal notes
    textwidth=50mm,
    textheight=130mm,
    top=71.86614pt,
    inner=35mm, 
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{maroon}{RGB}{128,0,0}
% Define a new command for the verse number that allows for future styling
% Define a new command for the verse number that allows for future styling
\newcommand{\versenum}[1]{%
  \kern1pt% Negative kern to reduce space before the verse number
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{\textcolor{maroon}{#1}}}%
  \kern0.5pt% Negative kern to reduce space after the verse number
}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{9.5pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.75pt}
 \lettrine[lines=4, findent=0pt, nindent=0pt, loversize=-0.99]{\initfamily \textcolor{maroon}{B}}lessed be the God and father of our Lord Jesus Christ. 
 \versenum{2}According to his great mercy, He has caused us to be born again, to a living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead.
\versenum{3}To an inheritance that is imperishable, undefiled, and unfading, kept in heaven for you and here is some more text to make the pushed text up top more noticeable
\end{document}
\end{document}


Welcome!  Have you tried loading the microtype package?

the over-long lines are not directly related to your verse numbers simply the line length is narrow and Christ doesn't hyphenate so TeX could find no good place to break the second line. In my answer I allowed it to stretch interword spaces more so it has more chance to find a line break without needing to hyphenate

unrelated but you may be interested in an accessible ASV at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/discussions/72

I'd never use Times for such text; but newtxtext is definitely a better choice than the obsolete times package.
I did some changes: with such narrow column, the font should be smaller, which is achieved by scaling at 90%, with a corresponding reduction of the baseline skip.
I modified the definition of \versenum: you inserted positive kerns rather than negative ones. Finally, microtype does wonders.
In order to allow hyphenation of the word following a verse number, I use \nobreak\hspace{0pt}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lettrine} % For creating drop caps
\usepackage{yfonts}   % For Goudy Initialen font
\usepackage{xcolor} % Provides \textcolor
% Set the page geometry with default text width
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=9.4in,
    paperheight=6.8in,
    headheight=0pt, % Remove header
    headsep=0pt,    % Remove space for header
    footskip=0pt,   % Remove footer
    marginparwidth=0pt, % Remove marginal notes
    marginparsep=0pt,   % Remove separation for marginal notes
    textwidth=50mm,
    textheight=130mm,
    top=71.86614pt,
    inner=35mm, 
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{maroon}{RGB}{128,0,0}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\initfamily\color{maroon}}
\newcommand{\versenum}[1]{%
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{\textcolor{maroon}{#1}}}%
  \nobreak\hspace{0pt}\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\dropcap}[1]{%
  \lettrine[
    lines=4,
    findent=0pt,
    nindent=0pt,
    loversize=-0.99
  ]{#1}{}%
}

\linespread{0.9}

\begin{document}

\dropcap{B}lessed be the God and father of our Lord Jesus Christ. 
\versenum{2}
According to his great mercy, He has caused us to be born again, 
to a living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead.
\versenum{3}To an inheritance that is imperishable, undefiled, and 
unfading, kept in heaven for you and here is some more text to make 
the pushed text up top more noticeable

\end{document}



You can allow more flexibility in the white space so the text justifies

But as you see, the verse numbers break the baseline spacing so I also hid the height of the superscript

 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lettrine} % For creating drop caps
\usepackage{yfonts}   % For Goudy Initialen font
\usepackage{xcolor} % Provides \textcolor
% Set the page geometry with default text width
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=9.4in,
    paperheight=6.8in,
    headheight=0pt, % Remove header
    headsep=0pt,    % Remove space for header
    footskip=0pt,   % Remove footer
    marginparwidth=0pt, % Remove marginal notes
    marginparsep=0pt,   % Remove separation for marginal notes
    textwidth=50mm,
    textheight=130mm,
    top=71.86614pt,
    inner=35mm, 
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{maroon}{RGB}{128,0,0}
% Define a new command for the verse number that allows for future styling
% Define a new command for the verse number that allows for future styling
\newcommand{\versenum}[1]{%
  \leavevmode % make sure the following is horizontal not vertical
  \kern1pt% Negative kern to reduce space before the verse number
  \smash{\textsuperscript{\textbf{\textcolor{maroon}{#1}}}}% hide the height
  \kern0.5pt% Negative kern to reduce space after the verse number
}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength\emergencystretch{1cm}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{9.5pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.75pt}
 \lettrine[lines=4, findent=0pt, nindent=0pt, loversize=-0.99]{\initfamily \textcolor{maroon}{B}}lessed be the God and father of our Lord Jesus Christ. 
 \versenum{2}According to his great mercy, He has caused us to be born again, to a living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead.
\versenum{3}To an inheritance that is imperishable, undefiled, and unfading, kept in heaven for you and here is some more text to make the pushed text up top more noticeable
\end{document}

